# How can I tell what category I'm in-- in the header?

Tags: categories

How can I identify what category the current page is showing in the `<head>`? Here's the code I have now:

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>
    <!-- set up for home page ad -->
<?php } elseif ( in_category( 'Restaurant Reviews' )) { ?>
    <!-- set up for restaurant reviews ad -->
<?php } else { ?>
    <!-- set up for run of site ad -->
<?php } ?>
```

This code fails on my "Restaurant Reviews" page... it always selects the "run of site" option.

As a test, lower down in the page, I used `the_category()` to see what categories WP thought the current page used, and I got "Chelsea, Manhattan, New York, Restaurant Reviews". And of course, the `in_category()` command works correctly there in the lower part of my page, and properly recognizes when it's in the "Restaurant Reviews" category.

So-- up there in the `<head>`, how can I tell when I'm in the "Restaurant Reviews" category?

Comment: Really, one downvote and no comment or answer? Sheesh, tough crowd...

Comment: Yeah, it can be at times. :) The downvote might be because the question is fairly easily answered via the Codex. But personally, I think confusing `is_category()` and `in_category()` is easy to do and common, and as such, this is a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`in_category( $category )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) conditional only returns true when the *current post has the specified category assigned*. If you want to determine when you are on a **category archive index page**, you should instead use [**`is_category( $category )`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category):

```
if ( is_category( 'Restaurant Reviews' ) ) {
    // The current page is the Restaurant Reviews
    // category archive index page; do something
}
```

Side note: [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) returns true when the current page is the *blog posts index*, which will not always be true for the site front page. If the site uses a static front page, the blog posts index will be on a separate, static page, and `is_home()` will **not** return true on the site front page. So, if you actually intend to query for the **site front page**, use [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page):

```
<?php 
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    // set up for home page ad
} elseif ( is_category( 'Restaurant Reviews' )) {
    // set up for restaurant reviews ad
} else {
    // set up for run of site ad
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you are in the `<head>`.  Take a look at the [Plugin API/Action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).  The `post` object is not set up until the `wp` hook. If you are adding this conditional, manually the header.pher *before* `wp_head()` you probably don't have anything to work with.

I'd try adding it via function to perhaps even the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

Comment: Actually, the query is already set, and all query conditionals known and available, by the time the template loads (after all, `template_redirect` relies on knowing the result of `template_loader` to determine the correct template to load from the template hierarchy - and the template hierarchy depends on the query conditionals.